# Importar um swift em outro swift

Tags: swift, xcode, importação

Quero importar um arquivo swift em outro arquivo swift, como proceder ?

[image: Tentativa de implementar a importação]

*Usando Xcode 7.0 beta 3 via Swift 2, em uma tentativa mal sucedida*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diferentemente do Object-C o swift trabalha como se fosse Java, ele verifica automaticamente as classes que você tem no projeto, interpretando elas como um objeto.

Assim sendo você pode Declarar um objeto:

```
let meni = Meni()
```

A partir da classe instanciada você pode pegar seu métodos.

Answer (score 0):

Para chamar uma classe dentro de outra classe não utilizamos o `import`. Dentro da classe `ViewController` você cria uma variável e coloca o valor. Exemplo: `let meni = Meni()`

Answer (score 0):

Use o import do swift quando quiser incluir pacotes:

```
import UIKit 
import Foundation
import MeuFramework        //Caso tenha criado o seu próprio framework
```

Arquivos .swift já inclusos no seu projeto, serão reconhecidos automaticamente, basta chamar o recurso desejado sem sem se preocupar com importá-lo em outro arquivo. Mas é essencial que ele esteja presente de alguma forma no seu projeto.